# Quantity in Cart Model Basic Logic Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, model, logic

I am trying to apply some very basic logic to my view but am so far failing.

What I would like to do is return item.discount_price if there are the following conditions:

1. The item.product_id is equal to 1
2. The Cart.item.quantity count is equal or higher than 2.

Currently I have the following:

Items Model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :cart

def price_check

    if  Item.product_id = 1 && Item.quantity.count >= 2 
        return Item.discount_price
    else
        return Item.unit_price
    end 

end
```

end

View

```
<% for item in @cart.items %>
<tr class="<%= cycle :odd, :even %>">
  ...
  <td class="price"><%= gbp(item.price_check) %></td>
  ...
</tr>
```

The associations are as follows:

```
Cart - has_many :items
Items - Belongs_to :cart and :products
Products - has_ many :items
```

The error I keep receiving:

```
 NoMethodError in Carts#show

Showing C:/Sites/checkout/app/views/carts/show.html.erb where line #12 raised:

undefined method `quantity' for #<Class:0x50c3058>

Extracted source (around line #12):

9:        <tr class="<%= cycle :odd, :even %>">
10:       <td><%=h item.product.name %></td>
11:       <td class="qty"><%= item.quantity %></td>
12:       <td class="price"><%= gbp(item.price_check) %></td>
13:       <td class="price"><%= gbp(item.full_price) %></td>
14:       <td><%= button_to 'Remove', item, :method => :delete %></td>
15:       </tr>

app/models/item.rb:12:in `price_check'
app/views/carts/show.html.erb:12:in `block in _app_views_carts_show_html_erb___389237738_48997308'
app/views/carts/show.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_carts_show_html_erb___389237738_48997308'
```

Any help people can offer to fix this would be much appreciated! Thanks E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RadBrad had the right idea, but the wrong implementation

```
def price_check
  # Product Discount for Lavender Heart (Product code 001, greater than 2 in cart)        
  # Thought: Shouldn't you check to see if the name of the item is "Lavender Heart"?
  #          Checking if the product_id is 1 makes this test brittle
  if product_id == 1 && cart.items.quantity.count >= 2 
    discount_price
  else
    unit_price
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Jason! Only one quick question, if the discount price is stored in the Product table (rather than the Item table where unit_price is) how can I reference the discount_price correctly?

Comment: In your `Item` model, add the following line: delegate :discount_price, :to => :product

Answer (score -1):

The first obvious problem is this:

```
if  Item.product_id = 1 && Item.quantity.count >= 2
```

You are asking to call the CLASS method product_id.  You want the instance method, i.e.

```
if @item.product_id == 1 && @item.quantity >= 2
```

Normally this would be preceded with:

```
@item = Item.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reponse. The issue I have is that with instance methods I keep receiving errors like `undefined method `product_id=' for nil:NilClass` and if I precede with `@item = Item.find(params[:id])` then I get `undefined local variable or method `params'` Any further help you can offer really would be much appreciated!

Comment: The params are only available in the controller.  In your view, you are looping through the cart items and calling an instance method (price_check) on each item. The instance method should only ask things about itself (is my product_id == 1 and does my cart have more than two items in it), and return the item's discount_price or unit_price.  My answer above should work.